# (strong law of large numbers) We played a game in a casino. $X_i$ the money we won or lost the i-th time....

Tags: probability, limits, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

[image]>We played a game in a casino. $X_i$ the money we won or lost the i-th time. Each time that we win, we take 1 dollar. When we lost, we lost 1 dollar. If p is the probability of winning and q the probability of losing, use the strong law of large numbers to prove that the average of which we win $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/n$ after n games, goes to infinity if p $\gt$ q, and to minus infinity if q $\gt$ p or to zero if p = q when we play infinite times (n goes to infinity).

Not sure if i understand.But what did I think.

$X_n =
\begin{cases}
 +1,  & p \\[2ex]
-1,  & q
\end{cases}$

If $p = q = p - q = 0 \to \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{0}{n}= 0 $

Now for the cases $p \gt q$ and $p \lt q$.

Now for the cases $p \gt q$ and $p \lt q$, I understand that the sum is positive ($p \gt q$) and negative ($p \lt q$), but does it go to plus infinity and minus infinity?

Comment: This just seems wrong, the long-term average should approach the expected value, which is certainly finite. The only thing I can think of is that there's a typo and the sum they meant was just $\sum X_i,$ the sum of the winnings, but that seems like a strange mistake to miss. Could you give your source for the problem?

Comment: @StephenDonovan it's from a list of exercises, it's a mixture of portuguese and spanish. It's from a list of exercises, it's a mixture of Portuguese and Spanish. It's kind of confusing, theoretically it was supposed to be just an application of the strong law of large numbers. But like I said, I didn't quite understand it either.

Comment: @StephenDonovan But the plain sum when $p=q$ does not actually approach zero.

Comment: @StephenDonovan If you want I can send you the original question?

Comment: I guess I would like to see the original, yeah. (although my Spanish is very rusty and was never that good to begin with, and my Portuguese is almost entirely nonexistent, so I can't promise that I'll be the most helpful)

Comment: Also, my apologies, you're right about the sum not approaching zero when $p = q,$ I'd overlooked that.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I don't know how to send it to you, and I also don't know how to put it in the comment, so I put it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so my interpretation of this question is simply as follows:

You play a gambling game where there is a probability of p that you win 1 dollar and q that you lose 1 dollar (clearly p+q=1). If you play n times, show that if p>q then your expected earnings as n goes to infinity is infinite, if p<q then your expected loss as n goes to infinity is infinite, and if p=q then you're expected not to gain or lose anything.

If this is the correct interpretation, then the proof is very obvious: every game, you are expected to earn p*(1)+q*(-1)=p-q dollars. Therefore by playing an infinite amount of games you are expected to make infinity*(p-q) dollars. If p>q then the limit is clearly infinity, if p<q then the limit is clearly negative infinity. If p=q note we get the indeterminate form infinity*0, so we can instead take the bottom approach instead:

For all finite n, the expected earnings/losings is 0 dollars. Therefore, since we can choose arbitrarily large N such that the amount of earnings is 0 for all n>N, by the definition of a limit, we know the answer is 0.

Answer (score 0):

We can roughly say that from $\lim_{n \to \infty}{P(|\frac{S_n}{n}-EX|\geq \epsilon)=0}$ where $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$, all of the random variables $X_i$ have the same distribution $X$ we can conclude that $\frac{S_n}{n} \approx EX=p-q>0$ almost surely from where we can derive that $S_n \approx n(p-q) \to +\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$ (If $p>q$ and $p$ is probability of winning 1 dollar. It's completely the same for the opposite case.